# Xamarin Forms: ios:Page.UseSafeArea is not working for all the children in CarouselPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel

I have a CarouselPage having 4 children. For every pages I have added `ios:Page.UseSafeArea`, but `SafeArea` property is working only for first 2 pages and for the remaining 2 pages the safe area feature is not working. My XF version is 4.7.0.1080 (latest one).

I found the same issue on [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3837), is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: CarouselPage has been deprecated in favor of CarouselView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom renderer to wrote your own `safeAreaInsets` and then assign it to `Page.Padding`. Here use a 200ms delay to wait the initialization of `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow`.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace App19F_8.iOS
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public CustomPageRenderer()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var inset = new Thickness();

                Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(200), () =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow != null)
                        {
                            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
                            {
                                var safeAreaInsets = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.SafeAreaInsets;
                                inset.Top = safeAreaInsets.Top;
                                inset.Bottom = safeAreaInsets.Bottom;
                                inset.Left = safeAreaInsets.Left;
                                inset.Right = safeAreaInsets.Right;
                            }
                        }

                        ContentPage page = e.NewElement as ContentPage;
                        page.Padding = inset;
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your Xamarin.forms project, make the page in your `CarouselPage` inherits from `CustomPage`.